# Can't run mysql from an Emacs shell buffer

Tags: mysql, emacs

When I try to run the 'mysql' command inside an Emacs shell buffer, it just sits there and never prints the "mysql> " prompt.  Any idea how I can get the 'mysql' executable to work inside an Emacs shell buffer?

Answer (score 3):

Emacs shell is a dumb terminal.  mysql does not run under such terminal.  You could use `M-x sql-mysql` to run mysql under Emacs, or, use `M-x term` to start eterm under emacs which can launch mysql without problems.

Comment: I second the suggestion to use sql-mysql. I use it frequently, particularly through tramp on servers that don't have remote sql client access.

Comment: I'd happily run sql-mysql, but it's misbehaving and I can't get any help figuring out why.  I described the problem in detail 11 days ago at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879206/problems-trying-to-use-mysql-in-conjunction-with-emacs.  There hasn't been a single response to my question.  Could those of you recommending sql-mysql help me figure out why sql-mysql is buffering its output and only dumping it in batches of 4,096 characters?

Comment: I looked at the other question.  On Windows, you got to add `(setq sql-mysql-options '("-C" "-t" "-f" "-n"))` to your _emacs.  Depending on the port mysql is listening to, you might add `"--port=PORT#"` to the sql-mysql-options.  This information is found at `M-x describe-variable` `sql-mysql-options`.